# Wrapping a series of closures

Tags: javascript, datatables, monkeypatching

I have inherited a large chunk of code wherein it has a large set of arrays of `DataTable` renderers. I'd like to insert some extra data in the data objects at the front without rewriting all of the renderers, only the ones that are actually affected.

The `columnDefs` field is generated to be an array of objects with a `render` function and often other fields as well (`targets`, `type`, etc.).  I'd like to rewrite this on the fly to have the `render` function be a wrapper that calls the original function. I'm not finding the right code to close on the original function so I can munge the data on the way through and still call that original function.

For example, given a columnDefs as:

```
var columnDefs = [
{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return stuff(row[3]);
  },
  "targets": 2
},
{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return stuff(row[0]);
  },
  "targets": 1
},
// etc.
]
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var mapper = function (def) {
    (function (d, old_render) {
        d.render = (data, type, row) => {
            let extra_data = undefined;
            if (row.length > 1 && typeof (row[0]) == 'object') {
                extra_data = row[0];
                row = row.slice(1);
            }
            return old_render(data, type, row, extra_data);
        }
    })(def, def.render);
};
columnDefs.forEach(mapper);
```

prior to calling `$("#my-datatable").DataTable({ ..., columnDefs: columnDefs, ... })`.

What is working so far is that the new render function is being called. However, `old_render` is consistently undefined when `render` is called, which of course dies.

Full code example [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f97hx4su/2/) for convenience, and also here:

```
function stuff(x) {
  return "<b>" + x + "</b>";
}

var columnDefs = [
{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return stuff(row[3]);
  },
  "targets": 2
},
{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return stuff(row[0]);
  },
  "targets": 1
},
]

var dataSource = [{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"f","g","h","i","j"}];
columnDefs.forEach(d => {
  d.render = function(old_render) {
    return (data, type, row) => {
      let extra_data = undefined;
      return old_render(data, type, row.map(, extra_data);
    };
  }(d.render);
});
var table = $("#my-table").DataTable({
processing: true,
data: dataSource,
columnDefs: columnDefs
});
```

And the HTML associated is just:

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p>
hello
</p>
<table id="my-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Update... JSLint is working, I'm just not sure why it's not in my larger code base. Back to the drawing board, I suppose, to figure out why.

Comment: You should create a runnable example. It looks like it should work and old_render should not be undefined

Comment: I don't really get what you try to do, because you seem to call the original render functions with a fourth argument, but those render functions never look at that argument...

Comment: @trincot I'll be adding that fourth argument later, to the render functions that care about the extra data, the rest will ignore it. First thing is to get the original render function to be called.

Comment: This is very difficult to interpret. I do want to point out that `typeof` is not enough to determine that a member of an array is an object.

Comment: I tried your code, It called `old_render` with no problem.

Comment: @zfrisch thanks. One problem at a time, I hadn't gotten that far before testing whether the closure would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if some of the records don't have an input render, then of course the old renderer can't be called. The number of columns being handled here were large enough that I didn't notice some of them don't have a renderer.

```
var columnDefs = [
{
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
    return stuff(row[3]);
  },
  "targets": 2
},
{
  //"render": function (data, type, row) {
  //  return stuff(row[0]);
  //},
  "targets": 1
},
]
```

Now when the code gets to the second column here, there is no render function, and so of course that is undefined. By wrapping the mapper with an `if (d.render) {...}`, the problem is thusly avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
function newRender(oldRender, data, type, row) {
    let extra_data = undefined;
    if (row.length > 1 && typeof (row[0]) == 'object') {
        extra_data = row[0];
        row = row.slice(1);
    }
    return oldRender(data, type, row, extra_data);
}

var mapper = function (def) {
    def.render = newRender.bind(null, def.render);
};

columnDefs.forEach(mapper);
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: As you pointed out, the original code worked, which I admit I don't think I checked so functionally there isn't any difference. My bad. My code does, however, remove the additional self-executing function which isn't required so removes the nesting and should be a bit quicker.